# Laravel Tinker quit when doing curl request

Tags: php, laravel, curl

When doing a cURL request in Laravel's tinker, tinker will unexpectedly quit when using an HTTPs url. I have no errors in my laravel logs or my apache2 logs. I cannot find any information online as to why I am getting this behavior. These requests work when running this outside of tinker.

Any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: Might be a PHP REPL bug.

Comment: So i tested REPL directly loading my classes and executing the curl request and it works just fine. So this issue is directly related to tinker or PsyShell